# Programing music in Desmos

Tags: desmos

I am looking to program a song on Desmos using the "hear the graph" button. I am fine with programming the notes, but I am having trouble creating a pause in the song where nothing plays for a short period of time in between some of the notes. Has anyone been able to do this ?

If the function to be played is undefined on some part of the domain, desmos just skips straight away to the next defined part without pausing.

Any insight is appreciated

I've tried making the function undefined on some part of the domain, desmos just skips straight away to the next defined part without pausing.

I've also tried making the function to on a very high value on the parts I wanted pauses so that it is outside the visible part of the graph on the screen but it just doesn't play anything when parts of the function are outside like that.